# Sony Camera Remote API request failed

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I've a Sony DSC-WX300 and want to access the remote api via wifi.
I already have discovered the device successfully and got a "camera" endpoint.

When I try to call any api method, such as "getAvailableApiList", I only get a http 404.

My url: `http://10.0.0.1:10000/sony/camera`

My request content: `{ "method": "getAvailableApiList", "params": [], "id":1, "version": "1.0"}`

I know the device is not on the office supported device list, but Sony provides an iOS app (PlayMemories Mobile) which can access and work with my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now.

The url was wrong. Instead of using "http://10.0.0.1:10000/sony/camera" as mentioned in the API docs I have to use "http://10.0.0.1:10000/camera".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using A5100, and the default URL is "http://192.168.122.1:8080/sony/camera". Maybe u can try this ?